# How to get a picture from a kinect with labview

Tags: c, kinect, robotics, labview

My class and I are trying to make a robot, we need to be able to take a picture using a kinect in Labview. We know how to get a skeleton from the kinect, but we can't figure out how to take a picture/video. Is there a DLL we need to download? We can't find anything on the internet but we know it's possible to do in labview. So do we need to write any code in C? Im pretty good with C so don't restrict your answer to just labview. All relevant answers are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We can't find anything on the internet but we know it's possible to do
>   in labview.

Personally, I have no experience with this, but a quick "LabVIEW Kinect" search on Google turns up any number of results, including some which show video ([example](http://labviewhacker.com/kinect.php)). Based on the videos and images I see there, it looks like they're using the IMAQ control to show the video, so I'm assuming you're going to need the vision toolkit for that. If you have an academic license, you might already have that, but even if not, you could try asking your local NI office for one, as they generally tend to support schools.

Answer (score 0):

I would go on ni.com and search for LabVIEW Kinect. There are links over there like this:
[Kinect LabVIEW Interface Using Microsoft Kinect API](http://zone.ni.com/devzone/cda/epd/p/id/6504)